# RestClient doesn't run callbacks

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I'm trying to fetch sObjects via MobileSDK.

I wrote following code that fetch Contacts but none of callback blocks of tryMap() and sink() called. (I see Neither of "tryMap" and fetched value on console.)

How can I fix this?
Am I missing something or I should not use request(forQuery: ) ?

```
    func fetchContact() {
        print("fetchContact");
        let query = "SELECT id, firstName, lastName FROM Contact;"

        let request = RestClient.shared.request(forQuery: query, apiVersion: nil)

        cancellable = RestClient.shared.publisher(for: request)
                .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .tryMap({ (response) -> Data in
                    debugPrint("tryMap")
                    return response.asData()
                })
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    switch completion {
                    case .finished:
                        break
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
                }, receiveValue: { value in
                    debugPrint(value)
                })
    }
```

This code is written in the forceios Swift template app to reproduce the problem.

**Environment**

MacOS 12.1
XCode 13.2.1
Mobile SDK 9.2

If there's lack of information, pointing it out is appreciated.

Comment: Supplement: In this code, I'm using query because I'm migrating old app with MobileSDK and trying to divert existing code (contains queries).

Answer (score 0):

*Solved*

I found that Model itself is disposed before the asynchronous process completes.